# is CAS (compare and SWAP ) work perfectly fine?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

Have a small doubt on the correctness of "compare and swap " in java , because

i am still thinking this CAS also have a chance to lost the values , for example

lets a shared resource S , with the value 5

and threads T1 and T2  , want to update the values with the new values  6 and 7 respectively .

1 . T1 compare the value with 5 and found same 
2. T2 compare the value with 5 and found same 
3 . T2 set the values to 7
4. T1 set the value to 6

so now here the value set by the T2 lost as the T1 reads the old current value which is 5 at that time.

can anyone please explain on this please

Comment: You are talking of [AtomicInteger.compareAndSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#compareAndSet(int,%20int). There is also the `weakCompareAndSet` that indeed can fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you described can't happen, due to the atomicity of CAS.

It's not "Compare-Then-Swap", it's "Compare-And-Swap". There's no separate phase for compare and another phase for swap. That's the whole beauty of it.

Comment: Hi Kayaman , so you mean to say that  Compare-And-Swap , always occur in the atomic manner , no separate individual steps  ?

Comment: thnx Kayaman , seems to be i missed the point  "atomicity of CAS"